# How can i check if an inputted variable either starts with "Q" or it is a number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new so plz help. i am writting a program that adds numbers. it asks for input and until "Q" is inputed it keeps asking for input

```
def add_num(vari = "" , total = 0):
    vari = input("Enter a num or press \"Q\" to stop: ")
    while (vari.startswith("Q") and int(vari).isdigit() ) == False:
        print("Error")
        vari = input("plz enter again: ")
    else:
        print("Nice")
```

there are no indentation error. The problem i have is how can i check if it starts with "Q" or it is a number. I think this is the code that has errors

```
while (vari.startswith("Q") and int(vari).isdigit() ) == False:
```

Comment: **Make it `or` not `and`** Also, check `isdigit()` for the string, not the int.   ->  `while (vari.startswith("Q") or vari.isdigit() ) == False:`

Comment: `while not vari.startswith('Q'):`. I don't understand the `int` check

Comment: `int(vari).isdigit()` cannot work. `isdigit` is a method of `str` class

Comment: Please elaborate more clear what your problem is. What do you expect? And what do you get instead? Please review our [SO Question Checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer. If you get an error message, please paste the error here.

Comment: You should include details about the error, especially the traceback which has details about on which line the error is located.

Answer (score 0):

`vari.isdigit()` is enough to check that all characters are digits.

You have a logic error in the while condition: it cannot be that `vari.startswith("Q")` and at the same time `vari.isdigit()`, so that would be always false, and comparing that to `False` would always be true.

Change it to `while (vari.startswith("Q") or vari.isdigit()) == False:`